# Hibernate: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to database.entity.Dokumenty

Tags: java, hibernate

I have little problem :( When I try do this:

```
List<Dokumenty> dokumentyList = 
        (List<Dokumenty>)dokumentyDAO.getDokumentyByTrasy(((Trasy)routeComboBox.getSelectedItem()).getId());

for (Dokumenty dokumenty : dokumentyList){}
```

then I get error in for loop:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   database.entity.Dokumenty

My DokumentyDAO looks like this:

```
public class DokumentyDAO{

    private static volatile DokumentyDAO instance = null;

    private DokumentyDAO() {}

    public static DokumentyDAO getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DokumentyDAO.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new DokumentyDAO();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public List<Dokumenty> getDokumentyByTrasy(long idTrasy){

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        Query query = session.createQuery(
                "FROM Dokumenty dokumenty "
                + "left join dokumenty.dostawy dostawy "
                + "left join dostawy.trasy trasy "
                + "left join dostawy.klienci klienci "
                + "where trasy.id = :idTrasy "
                + "and dostawy.aktywny = 'A' ");
               // + "order by klienci.nrKlienta, klienci.nazwaKlienta, dokumenty.nrDok ");

        query.setParameter("idTrasy", idTrasy);

        return query.list();     
    }

}
```

And Dokumenty :

```
public class Dokumenty  implements java.io.Serializable{

     private long id;
     private Uzytkownicy uzytkownicy;
     private Dostawy dostawy;
     private String nrDok;
     private String typDok;
     private long JWydane;
     private long eurWydane;
     private long h1Wydane;
     private long e2Wydane;
     private long JZwrot;
     private long eurZwrot;
     private long h1Zwrot;
     private long e2Zwrot;
     private Date dataMod;
     private char aktywny;

    public Dokumenty() {
    }


    public Dokumenty(long id, Uzytkownicy uzytkownicy, Dostawy dostawy, String nrDok, String typDok, long JWydane, long eurWydane, long h1Wydane, long e2Wydane, long JZwrot, long eurZwrot, long h1Zwrot, long e2Zwrot, char aktywny) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uzytkownicy = uzytkownicy;
        this.dostawy = dostawy;
        this.nrDok = nrDok;
        this.typDok = typDok;
        this.JWydane = JWydane;
        this.eurWydane = eurWydane;
        this.h1Wydane = h1Wydane;
        this.e2Wydane = e2Wydane;
        this.JZwrot = JZwrot;
        this.eurZwrot = eurZwrot;
        this.h1Zwrot = h1Zwrot;
        this.e2Zwrot = e2Zwrot;
        this.aktywny = aktywny;
    }
    public Dokumenty(long id, Uzytkownicy uzytkownicy, Dostawy dostawy, String nrDok, String typDok, long JWydane, long eurWydane, long h1Wydane, long e2Wydane, long JZwrot, long eurZwrot, long h1Zwrot, long e2Zwrot, Date dataMod, char aktywny) {
       this.id = id;
       this.uzytkownicy = uzytkownicy;
       this.dostawy = dostawy;
       this.nrDok = nrDok;
       this.typDok = typDok;
       this.JWydane = JWydane;
       this.eurWydane = eurWydane;
       this.h1Wydane = h1Wydane;
       this.e2Wydane = e2Wydane;
       this.JZwrot = JZwrot;
       this.eurZwrot = eurZwrot;
       this.h1Zwrot = h1Zwrot;
       this.e2Zwrot = e2Zwrot;
       this.dataMod = dataMod;
       this.aktywny = aktywny;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Uzytkownicy getUzytkownicy() {
        return this.uzytkownicy;
    }

    public void setUzytkownicy(Uzytkownicy uzytkownicy) {
        this.uzytkownicy = uzytkownicy;
    }
    public Dostawy getDostawy() {
        return this.dostawy;
    }

    public void setDostawy(Dostawy dostawy) {
        this.dostawy = dostawy;
    }
    public String getNrDok() {
        return this.nrDok;
    }

    public void setNrDok(String nrDok) {
        this.nrDok = nrDok;
    }
    public String getTypDok() {
        return this.typDok;
    }

    public void setTypDok(String typDok) {
        this.typDok = typDok;
    }
    public long getJWydane() {
        return this.JWydane;
    }

    public void setJWydane(long JWydane) {
        this.JWydane = JWydane;
    }
    public long getEurWydane() {
        return this.eurWydane;
    }

    public void setEurWydane(long eurWydane) {
        this.eurWydane = eurWydane;
    }
    public long getH1Wydane() {
        return this.h1Wydane;
    }

    public void setH1Wydane(long h1Wydane) {
        this.h1Wydane = h1Wydane;
    }
    public long getE2Wydane() {
        return this.e2Wydane;
    }

    public void setE2Wydane(long e2Wydane) {
        this.e2Wydane = e2Wydane;
    }
    public long getJZwrot() {
        return this.JZwrot;
    }

    public void setJZwrot(long JZwrot) {
        this.JZwrot = JZwrot;
    }
    public long getEurZwrot() {
        return this.eurZwrot;
    }

    public void setEurZwrot(long eurZwrot) {
        this.eurZwrot = eurZwrot;
    }
    public long getH1Zwrot() {
        return this.h1Zwrot;
    }

    public void setH1Zwrot(long h1Zwrot) {
        this.h1Zwrot = h1Zwrot;
    }
    public long getE2Zwrot() {
        return this.e2Zwrot;
    }

    public void setE2Zwrot(long e2Zwrot) {
        this.e2Zwrot = e2Zwrot;
    }
    public Date getDataMod() {
        return this.dataMod;
    }

    public void setDataMod(Date dataMod) {
        this.dataMod = dataMod;
    }
    public char getAktywny() {
        return this.aktywny;
    }

    public void setAktywny(char aktywny) {
        this.aktywny = aktywny;
    }

}
```

Aby idea whats is wrong? I ran out of ideas :/

Comment: Put a break point before the for cycle but after the dao invocation and check the content of the dokumentyList. According to your log there isn't a Dokumenty instance in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your are using joins so Hibernate is not returning a list of Dokumenty but instead a list of arrays (think a list of rows), the first entry of each array would be the Dokumenty, the second one the dostawy and so on

Answer (score 1):

The issue s that you have not told Hibernate how to map the Dokumenty Java class to the database tables. Thus you get back  untyped Object s in the query

You need a XML mapping or Java annotations ([Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/ch03.html#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-annotations-entity)) to map the Java objects to the database tables including mapping fields to the primary key and associations of objects (these associations tell Hibernate how the tables are related and let Hibernate generate the code to join tables rather than you doing the joins manually as you have done.